# Shooting method still relevant?

Tags: numerical-analysis-of-pde

I'm preparing to teach a "Numerical Analysis II" course next term, and in previous years this course involved a section on the shooting method for solving one-dimensional boundary value problems. This made me wonder, is the shooting method still relevant enough that it is worth teaching it to undergraduates? Personally I can't think of a scenario where the shooting method would offer any advantage over the finite difference method combined with a fast solver for band-limited matrices.

Comment: It is still used in optimal control.https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C28&as_ylo=2015&q=multiple+shooting+control&btnG=

Comment: Interesting! Can you elaborate a bit more on the type of problem for which it is used, and why the shooting method is suitable for these kinds of problems?

Comment: Optimal control equations result in BVP to be solved on 1d (time) domain. So essentially, you are solving for intersection of solution of two Cauchy (IVP) problems with half of boundary values known on one end, and half on other end. By guesssing the rest, one integration is started from t=0, and one is started back from t=T (final time). That makes shooting a natural candidate,

Comment: You can read more here: http://www.anilvrao.com/Publications/ConferencePublications/trajectorySurveyAAS.pdf